# Show a view in background of other view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a progress bar in background of image view is it possible?
Please help?

Comment: Post a picture of what you're trying to say. A layout such as linear with a progressbar linked at the bottom would still technically be in the "background".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background1" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background2" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background3" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

create a xml file in drawalbe as above and in layout.xml using

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/music_volume_seekbar_style"
```

are you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

For any views it is impossible. But if you have `ImageView` you can use method `ImageView.setAlpha(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can overlap two views (ImageView and progress bar). Set the ImageView to be VISIBLE and your progress bar to have visibility GONE by default.

When you want you can make your progress bar visible. Note that you need to set the background of your ProgressBar transparent.

Check more about how to make a view's background transparent here: http://www.41post.com/4213/programming/android-transparent-or-translucent-view-background